# How to create a nicer transition from our wood and tile

Tags: flooring, tile, trim, caulking

We have an old house were the previous owners installed tile in our kitchen and left the original wood floors in the dining room. He finished the tile with a tile edge trim, but the there is still a gap between the wood floor and this trim as well as some discoloration on the wood. The gap is too small for a transition T-molding I believe, so any ideas of how we clean this up?[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable; you may get several opinions but we don't know what you would like to see. Do you want a molding "bump"? Do you just want to clean up the ends of the wood and fill the space?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to get rid of the gap where the wood doesn't meet the metal trim and if we could cover where the wood ends that would be great

Comment: You are asking 2 questions. Discoloration and Gap. This site works better with one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

I think here I would be tempted to use an oscillating saw to trim the ends of the boards, creating a small gap into which a T-molding can be inserted.